# Returning Other Column Data from Search

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a simple form, to return values from a database using the PHP below, how do I return other values within the row?

Currently it's returning the product ID, I would like to return the Product name and description as well.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "master");
if (isset($_GET['keywords'])) {
    $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);
    $query    = $db->query("
            SELECT productID, productName
            FROM promo
            WHERE productID LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
            OR productID LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
        ");
?>

   <div class="resul-count">
    Found <?php
    echo $query->num_rows;
?> Results.
    </div>

    <?php
    if ($query->num_rows) {
        while ($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
?>
               <div class="result">
                    <a href="#"><?php
            echo $r->productID;
?></a>
                </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Search</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="./search.php" method="get">

    <label>Search By Product ID:
  <input type="text" name="keywords">
 </label>
    <input type="submit" value="search" autocomplete="off">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The query is already retrieving productName column, refernence it the same way as productId, e.g. `echo $r->productName;`  To get the description, that would need to be included in the SELECT list of the query... `SELECT productId, productName, productDescription ...`  then when the row is fetched (as an object), we can reference `$r->productDescription` just like we reference `$r->productId`.

Comment: See about prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add the product description to the select statement if you want it to return a value like so:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "master");
if (isset($_GET['keywords'])) {
    $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);
    $query    = $db->query("
            SELECT productID, productName, productDescription 
            FROM promo
```

next, this WHERE Clause is redundant. you are searching every item twice with the same search

```
            WHERE productID LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
           // OR productID LIKE '%{$keywords}%' -- redundant code. same as the first test. 
        ");
?>

   <div class="resul-count">
    Found <?php echo $query->num_rows;?> 
    Results.
    </div>

    <?php
    if ($query->num_rows) {
        while ($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
    ?>
    <div class="result">
       <a href="#"><?php
       echo $r->productID;
```

and lastly you are only echoing out the product ID. If you want the other two items you need to echo them out as well like so:

```
       echo $r->productName;
       echo $r->productDescription;
       ?></a>
    </div>
     <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

put that all together for:

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "master");
    if (isset($_GET['keywords'])) {
        $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);
        $query    = $db->query("
                SELECT productID, productName, productDescription 
                FROM promo
                WHERE productID LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
               // OR productID LIKE '%{$keywords}%' -- redundant code. same as the first test. 
            ");
?>
<div class="resul-count">
    Found <?php echo $query->num_rows;?> 
    Results.
</div>

<?php
    if ($query->num_rows) {
        while ($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
?>
<div class="result">
    <a href="#">
        <?php
            echo $r->productID; 
            echo $r->productName;
            echo $r->productDescription;
        ?>
    </a>
</div>
<?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank You a Million, ThatGuy

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: That Error means one of the names is wrong where `echo $r->productID; ` is being executed. I need to see you database column names in to fix that. I don't know what the columns are called in your data base so I took a guess. Change the name to the actual column name in both the select statement and in the object notation and it should work.

Comment: Or post a screen shot of the database column names and i can fix it.